Changing parent value, when child meet specific conditions
I'm currently struggling with some jq, hope somebody can help.
Given is the following JSON structure:
[
    {
        "id": "100",
        "input": "ChecklistState",
        "value": "-",
        "sub": [
            {
                "id": "110",
                "input": "Text",
                "value": "foo",
                "sub": []
            },
            {
                "id": "120",
                "input": "ChecklistState",
                "value": "OK",
                "sub": []
            },
            {
                "id": "130",
                "input": "ChecklistState",
                "value": "OK",
                "sub": []
            },
            {
                "id": "140",
                "input": "ChecklistState",
                "value": "OK",
                "sub": []
            }
        ]
    }
]

I need a filter, that changes "value" to "OK" of the parent ("id": "100"), when every child in "sub" with "input" value "Text" has no empty "value" and every "input" value "ChecklistState" has value "OK". ( -> 110 not empty, 120, 130 and 140 "OK")
A generally usable filter (checking for the input) would be great, but I also wouldn't mind a solution, where I check for every child-ID individually.
I've tried accessing the values of the childs with
select(.sub[]?.id=="xxx").value
and concatenating that in an if-then-else-end-Block, however the results was, that the conditions seemed not to work.
Please note: due to software requirements, I need to use jq v1.5

Please post the entire script you tried


I need a filter, that changes the value of the parent (ID 100) to OK, when 110s value is not empty and 120, 130 and 140s value is OK. Please note: due to software requirements, I need to use jq v1.5

Here's one way using from_entries to generate an index object from the .sub array that can be queried:
map(                                                        # for all items
  if .sub | map(.key = .id) | from_entries                  # create an index
    | [."110" != "OK", .["120","130","140"] == "OK"] | all  # match condition
  then .value = "OK"
  else .
  end
)

Demo


I need a filter, that changes the value of the parent (ID 100) to OK, when every child with input type "Text" has no empty value and every input type "ChecklistState" has value OK. ( -> 110 not empty, 120, 130 and 140 "OK")

In this case, I'd apply all directly onto the .sub array with the modified conditions.
map(
  if .sub | all(
    .input == "Text" and .value != "" or
    .input == "ChecklistState" and .value == "OK"
  )
  then .value = "OK"
  else .
  end
)

Demo

Output:
[
  {
    "id": "100",
    "input": "ChecklistState",
    "value": "OK",
    "sub": [
      {
        "id": "110",
        "input": "Text",
        "value": "foo",
        "sub": []
      },
      {
        "id": "120",
        "input": "ChecklistState",
        "value": "OK",
        "sub": []
      },
      {
        "id": "130",
        "input": "ChecklistState",
        "value": "OK",
        "sub": []
      },
      {
        "id": "140",
        "input": "ChecklistState",
        "value": "OK",
        "sub": []
      }
    ]
  }
]

